# Class 'Mage' not found in Controller.php on line 835

Tags: php, magento

Struggled fo serveral days, but not solved.

I get error when clicking magento connect manager in backend

`PHP Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in "/abc/downloader/Maged/Controller.php on line 835"`

The error also ocurred when just access http://domainname/downloader
 
The same code works for another host with OS Ubuntu.  The error host is CentOS release 6.5
 
It is not a privilege problem. I run `chmod -R a+rwx *` to change privilege of all folders in testing environment, but error still exist.

By tracing `/abc/downloader/Maged/Controller.php on line 835`

It is invoking `Mage::setIsDownloader();`

Before that line is `include_once $this->getMageFilename();`

`Controller.php` works. I add a line of output of the variable `$this->getMageFilename();`, it shows `/abc/app/Mage.php"`

And I write a test php and put it in downloader folder. It works:

```
echo "hi";
include_once('/abc/app/Mage.php');
 
echo Mage::getVersion();
```

The test php works. When accessed by `http://.../downloader/test.php` It can output   
`hi1.7.0.2`

I also tried to add `include_once('/abc/app/Mage.php');` manually in `index.php` of downloader folder, but fails.

Cache and session are removed from both `/abc/var` and `/tmp/magento`

Any hint to further trace the problem?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue? I am getting the same